# Logical Backup strategy in large Oracle Databases

Tags: oracle, backup, delete, datapump

in Oracle databases, I would like to know if it is advisable to make logical backups with exp or expdp in large databases with large volumes of data, greater than terabyte, I have seen several systems with Oracle that have large sizes and only perform physical backups With RMAN, I wonder what the strategy would be if a table was deleted for some reason ...? What do you do in such cases? What would be a save strategy in these large Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

With RMAN you can do point-in-time recovery (if properly) configured, so you could restore the database to the moment before the drop. Also, you can even restore just a single table from a [backup](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/rman-recovering-tables-partitions.html#GUID-FBD1224C-822F-45E7-898D-1DEC3C6FD7A1). Other than that you have the [recyclebin](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/RECYCLEBIN.html#GUID-B6F1AA5B-DF1E-4EAF-BDFD-E70EFBAD997A) from which you can recover dropped tables and you have also Flashback Database. So to recover from a dropped table there are plenty of options - without an export.

In my career I have only once used daily exports as part of the backup strategy, but we stopped that once you could restore a single table from backup.

Regards,
Daniel